# OnKey Not Running Sub

Tags: arguments, option-type

I have an Excel 365 spread sheet where the user is not allowed to save with incomplete data.  This works fine.  But I need a way to override that for my own use and save anyway.  When I use the defined key combination CTRL-ALT-PGDN I get an error 'argument not optional'.  What is wrong with this code?

Application.OnKey "%^{PgDn}", "Secretsave"

Public Sub Secretsave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox "In secret save"
ThisWorkbook.Save SaveChanges = True
End Sub

I want it to save the workbook.
Thanks. Any help is appreciated.